# Python type annotation for identical, generic function signatures

Tags: python, generics, type-annotation

`typing.Callable` takes two "arguments": the argument type(s) and the return type. The argument type should be either `...`, for arbitrary arguments, or a list of explicit types (e.g., `[str, str, int]`).

Is there a way of representing `Callable`s that have exactly the same, albeit arbitrary, signatures for generics?

For example, say I wanted a function that took functions and returned a function with the same signature, I could do this if I knew the function signature upfront:

```
def fn_combinator(*fn:Callable[[Some, Argument, Types], ReturnType]) -> Callable[[Some, Argument, Types], ReturnType]:
    ...
```

However, I don't know the argument types upfront and I want my combinator to be suitably general. I had hoped that this would work:

```
ArgT = TypeVar("ArgT")
RetT = TypeVar("RetT")
FunT = Callable[ArgT, RetT]

def fn_combinator(*fn:FunT) -> FunT:
    ...
```

However, the parser (at least in Python 3.7) doesn't like `ArgT` in the first position. Is `Callable[..., RetT]` the best I can do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Prior to Python 3.10

If you don't need to change the function signature at all, you should define `FuncT` as a `TypeVar`:

```
FuncT = TypeVar("FuncT", bound=Callable[..., object])

def fn_combinator(*fn: FuncT) -> FuncT:
    ...
```

> Is there a way of representing Callables that have exactly the same, albeit arbitrary, signatures for generics?

Unlike a type alias (e.g.: `FuncT = Callable[..., RetT]`), `TypeVar` allows the type checker to infer a dependency between the parameters and the return value, ensuring that the function signatures will be exactly the same.

However, this approach is utterly limited. Using `FuncT` makes it difficult to properly type the returned function (See [this mypy issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1927)).

```
def fn_combinator(*fn: FuncT) -> FuncT:
    def combined_fn(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        ...

    # return combined_fn  # Won't work. `combined_fn` is not guaranteed to be `FuncT`
    return cast(FuncT, combined_fn)
```

This is the best we can do as of Python 3.7 due to the limitation of `Callable` introduced in [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#callable).

> ... only a list of parameter arguments ([A, B, C]) or an ellipsis (signifying "undefined parameters") were acceptable as the first "argument" to typing.Callable. --- [PEP 612](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0612/#valid-use-locations)

---

### Python 3.10+

Fortunately, type annotations for callables becomes more flexible in Python 3.10 with `typing.ParamSpec` (the so-called "parameter specification variable") and `typing.Concatenate` proposed in [PEP 612](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0612/#the-components-of-a-paramspec). This extends `Callable` to support annotating more complicated callables.

This means that you will be able to do the following:

```
P = ParamSpec("P")
RetT = TypeVar("RetT")

def fn_combinator(*fn: Callable[P, RetT]) -> Callable[P, RetT]:
    ...
```

It also allows us the fully type check the returned callable without using `cast`:

```
def fn_combinator(*fn: Callable[P, RetT]) -> Callable[P, RetT]:
    def combined_fn(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> RetT:
        ...

    return combined_fn
```

See the release notes [here](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html).